# Could not find a connected Android device. (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)

Tags: android, ruby, mobile, automation, appium

I am unable to run my android automation test and I get the following error message:

```
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. 
Original error: Could not find a connected Android device. 
(Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
```

I also get this message on the Appium server logs:

```
[ADB] Could not find devices, restarting adb server...
[ADB] Restarting adb
```

I have tried `adb devices` and I get an empty list. How can I add a few dummie android devices or will the developer do this?

Can somebody please be kind enough to give me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the command `adb kill-server` and then try running `adb devices`.Hope this helps.